# How can i set the height of stackview present inside another stackview whose distribution is fill equally distribution

Tags: ios, uistackview

I need to create a login page which should be same across all the screen so created a parent stackview with constraints 20 for top,bottom,leading and trailing and its distribution is fill equally as there are 9 uiviews present in it. I want to increase height of stackview which consist 3 button with constraints ratio of 1:1 respectively. I need to set the height of this stackview. But once i set a constraints entire view goes off the screen. same with case of giving height to button.

[pls see this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr3sX.png) I need to create the same screen but how can i give the height in the ratio or something of this nested stackview ?

Comment: You have a Vertical stack view, with 9 views, with distribution set to Fill Equally... but you want to change the height of one of those views? Then it's no longer "Fill Equally". Have you tried using Equal Spacing or Equal Centering?

Comment: And... you are talking about the "row of 3 icons (in, g+, f)", correct? And you want that row to be taller than the others?

Comment: yes i want row of 3 to be taller than other always

Comment: ok... do you want it to be a fixed height for all screen sizes? so, the "icon row" height should be 100-pts, and the other rows should be sized-to-fit? or do you want "icon row" to be a percentage height?

Comment: "fill equally" distribution won't fit your requirement. Use some other options, like if spacing is equal then "equal spacing" or if proportional "Fill proportionally"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another view inside this stack view (containing images) and make the content hugging priority of image stack view higher than the view (which we added extra) . Set the view button height as X% to Stackview or whatever you want and set aspect ratio as 1:1 (I have done this in this [example project](https://github.com/nanduahmed/uistackview/tree/Q46888031))

This will try to keep best height in all screen sizes and also will maintain the aspect ratio.

However you cannot make the height greater than the distribution of uistackview